# does not contain a public instance definition for 'getenumerator' for each error thrown

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through a list that contains student data using `foreach` method however I get the error `QA does not contain a public instance definition for 'getenumerator' for each`.

My QA class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class QA
    {
        private List<Student> students;

        public QA()
        {
            students = new List<Student>();
            string line;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Users/jvb/Desktop/Students.txt"))
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                var s = line.Split(',');
                int id = int.Parse(s[0]);
                int houseNo = int.Parse(s[3]);
                var status = int.Parse(s[7]);
                Student sData = new Student(id, s[1], s[2], houseNo, s[4], s[5], s[6], (StudentStatus)status);
                AddStudent(sData);
            }
        }


        public List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return students;
        }

        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

This simply loops through a text file with various bits of data and adds each student to a `students` list. Inside my `program.cs` file I created an instance of the QA class and tried to loop through it like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QA students = new QA();

            foreach (var s in students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.GetStudents());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite new to c#, could anyone care to explain what I am misunderstanding/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are direct use object that is not enuerable, you have to access it member which is implemented IList and that is enumerable.

you are doing it all wrong.

You are iterating class object which is not iterable. you don't need foreach.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        QA students = new QA();
        var studentList= s.GetStudents();  //you get all the students not you can iterate on this lidt

     foreach(var student in studentList)
     {
        //here you can access student property like
         Console.WriteLine(student.Name);  //I assume Name is a property of Student class
     }
    }
```

Comment: This fixes the error but I not have no access to the `GetStudents()` method?

Comment: @JayVB You are doing this... students.GetStudents()  right ?

Comment: Oh I see, that fixes it. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Thankyou!